# What is a grep command performs?

Tags: unix, grep

Im trying to understand this unix command but im not quite an expert on this, could someone explain it more in detail?

```
grep '^.\{167\}02'
```

What does it perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page (`man grep`)

> grep searches the named input FILEs (**or standard input if no files are named**, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.

Check the part in bold: if you don't specify the files you want to search in, it will just wait and listen to your keyboard input and do a regex match for each new line that you type.

If you want to test it, I suggest you using an easier regex, maybe with less characters like this one: `^.\{3\}02` and see what happens:

```
$ grep '^.\{3\}02'
02
002
0002
00002 <-- this matches and will later be printed and highlighted
00002
```

You don't normally use `grep` and type lines yourself to see if matches, but give it files as argument, or another input using the pipe:

```
ls -la | grep '^.\{167\}02'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found line(s) which starts (`^`) from any (`.`) 167 symbols which has been followed by 02.